# What technology can help to delegating method implementation in java?

Tags: java

I have some pojos in my java projects, I want to add some annotations to methods on them to load associated objects.

for example :

```
public class Plan {
    
    private long id;
    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(type=Task.class, ref="$id=planId")
    public List<Task> getTasks(){
        // empty body
    }
    

}
```

the actual implementation is quite heavy, I want my pojo keep simple and pure, so when Plan#getTasks get invoked, I want to delegate to external implementation.

What technology in java can help to achieve this goal?

Comment: What do you mean, external implementation?  Do you just want to call another function?